# Как правильно спарсить элемент в simple_html_dom

Tags: php, парсер, simple-html-dom

Пытаюсь спарсить цену с сайта (по `class="detail-price-uah"`), но она грузится не на все указанные товары, то есть к одним товарам грузится к другим нет. И с каждым запуском меняется, то есть сейчас у этого товара цена подгрузилась, перезапустил парсер, уже у него цены нет, но есть у другого товара.

На сколько я понял цена на сайте исходнике подгружается из скрипта, но рядом лежит `<meta itemprop="price" content="399">`
Здесь значение `content="399"` и есть нужная мне цена, то есть "399".

Но добраться до этого `content` я никак не могу. Как это можно сделать? Или как можно подгрузить данные прямо из скрипта?

Видел что вроде бы можно как то регуляркой все что нужно вытянуть, но никак пока не пойму как ее написать.

Возможно задаю глупые вопросы, я только начинаю изучать это все.

Мой код парсера:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
include_once('lib/curl_queri.php');
include_once('lib/simple_html_dom.php'); 

$html = curl_get('https://rozetka.com.ua/uslugi/c153670/'); //подключаюсь к сайту донору
$dom = str_get_html($html); //получаю код страницы

$services = $dom->find('.g-i-tile-i-title'); //ищу на странице товары (сервисы)

foreach($services as $service){

    $a = $service->find('a', 0); //сохраняю ссылки на сервисы

    $one = curl_get($a->href); //перехожу на страницу по сохраненной ссылке
    $one_dom = str_get_html($one); //получаю код страницы

    $price = $one_dom->find('.detail-price-uah'); //ищу на странице цену по классу
    echo $price . ' --- ' . $a->href . '<br>'; //вывожу цены и ссылки на сервисы

}

?>
```

Comment: а зачем вы переходите вообще на вложенные страницы? если цены есть и в самом списке?

Comment: нашли вы свои `"g-i-tile-i-box-desc`, ссылку получили, потом нашли внутри тэг `script`. внутри откопали строку `pricerawjson = '(.*?)'`, сделали `url_decode`, потом `json_decode`, и взяли из него поле `price`

Comment: @teran Перехожу на вложенные страницы потому что мне нужно будет брать еще описание товара и возможно еще какую - то информацию которая есть только в карточке.

Comment: @teran Благодарю за ответ! Вы можете еще подсказать, как это правильно записать в коде?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если мой коммент к вопросу расписать более подробно, то получается нечто вроде такого.

```
$content = file_get_contents("https://rozetka.com.ua/uslugi/c153670/");

$html = str_get_html($content);

$result = [];

$items = $html->find(".g-i-tile-i-box-desc");
foreach($items as $item){

    $href  = $item->find(".g-i-tile-i-title a", 0)->href;
    $price = null;

    $script = $item->find('script', 0)->innertext;

    if(preg_match("/pricerawjson\\s=\\s'(.*?)'/", $script, $matches)){
        $json = urldecode($matches[1]);
        $data = json_decode($json, true);

        $price = $data['price'];
    }


    $result[] = ['href' => $href, 'price' => $price];
}


print_r($result);
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!